# I can't read my FirebaseDatabase. It shows an warning as: W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't read my `FirebaseDatabase`. It shows an warning as: `W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null`.

My code is:

```
private void readData(final ReadData readData) {
    Log.i("test", "Users 1: " + ref);
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(!snapshot.exists()) return;
            users.clear();
            totalUsers.clear();
            Log.i("test", "Users 2: " + ref);
            int userNo = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot items : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (items.exists()) {
                    UserChangeInfo user = items.getValue(UserChangeInfo.class);
                    assert user != null;
                    totalUsers.add(user);
                    if (!user.getNewPassword().equals("")) {
                        users.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
            readData.onCallback();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
}
```

For better understanding, I used `Log.i()`.
It executes first `Log` where "Users1: + ref" is showed but it doesn't execute the `Log` where "Users2: + ref" should be showed. That means, I guess, program doesn't enter in
`ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener())`. but Why??

1. Declared ref as: `ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("change request");`
2. ref is not null: `ref =  https://myFirebaseAppLink/change%20request`
3. Authentication is allowed.
4. Used the dependencies: `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')` and other firebase dependandencies.
5. Wi-fi connection is Okay. (Other firebase apps is working also).
6. App is connected with firebase.

Still it is showing this problem.
Why?
Please, I'm stuck here for days!!

Comment: That warning message might not be relevant at all.  If there is an error, your code is doing nothing with it.  Log the exception in onCancelled if you want to know if something went wrong.

Comment: The program does not execute the `onCancelled` at all.
Actually the program does not enter in `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method at all.
So none of the `Log`s in `onDataChange()` or `onCancelled()` executes.
Why?

@DougStevenson

Comment: @Fahad Are you sure you have internet access on the device?

Comment: Yes sir. Everything that are related to internet is working fine.
Can you please find me the problem?
I'm stuck here for days. :( :( 
@AlexMamo

Comment: I have the same problem, sometimes the solution is File> Invalidate Caches / Restart, and other times not, and there are more times not, and I also have a couple of days with this problem, if you have managed to fix it, it would be a good idea share the solution